# Is there a possibility to write a random letter generator as short as in python?

Tags: java, random, letter

So I want to shorten my code and I asked myself if there is any possibility that a Random Letter generator in Java is as short as in python. In python it's just one a one liner.

The following Code is my Code yet:

```
int random = (int) Math.random()*25;

String[] letters ={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"}; 

String letter = letters[random];
```

Comment: Hi Pereki, it would be nice to post your code :)

Comment: How short can Python do it, and what metric of "short" do you want? Characters? Steps? Something else?

Comment: If you ask for a comparison, it would be nice to know what we're comparing to, i.e. how "short" can Python do it?

Comment: What happened to `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Comment: lol, thats kind of funny, thank you for your reminder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If "short" just means one line, then any of these would do:

```
char letter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt((int) (Math.random() * 26));

char letter = (char) ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt('a', 'z'+1);

char letter = (char) ('a' + Math.random() * 26);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ASCII table.  97 = 'a', so just add your random number to that and convert to char.

[ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/)

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char z = (char)(97 + Math.random()*26);
        System.out.println("z = " + z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `'a'`, not 97, to make the code a bit more self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest version to create 100 Characters:

```java
Character[] result = new Random().ints(100,'a','z'+1).mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch).toArray(Character[]::new);
```